# Pytorch Dataloader - How to to train with various train & val dataset sizes (10k Samples, 20k... 100k samples) to compare dataset size impact?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, transfer-learning

i want to compare model performances depending on various sizes of the training and validation dataset.

I'd like to be able to build a loop which trains my pytorch model using 10k train and 1k val data and linearly increase the dataset sizes until 100k train and 10k val dataset sizes.

I also need to take target classes into consideration, therefore implement stratified splits somehow. I don't know where and how to implement this.

Does anyone have an idea how to easly implent this into my dataset class defintion?
Can i implement it here somehow?

```
def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inputFolderDataset.imgs)
```

I thought of additionally defining an array "sizes = [10000,20000...100000]" to iterature through.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, content, max_length=None):
        # the DataLoader will only shuffle instances in [0, max_length], maybe shuffle
        # the instances here to not have smaller datasets being subsets of the larger ones
        self.content = content
        self.max_length = max_length or float("inf")
    
    def __len__(self):
        return min(self.max_length, len(self.content))
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.content[idx]
    
train = MyDataset(np.arange(1000), 
                     max_length=100)

loader = DataLoader(train, 
                    batch_size=25,
                    shuffle=True)

for entry in loader:
    print(entry)
```

Output:

```
tensor([ 8, 33, 50, 40, 85, 32, 96, 58, 64, 78, 35, 97, 29, 73, 36, 68, 82, 62,
        89, 66, 48, 79, 99, 93,  6], dtype=torch.int32)
tensor([52,  3, 26, 28, 77, 95, 24, 10,  7, 20, 16,  1, 25, 92, 56, 91, 30, 14,
        65, 51, 74, 98, 46, 61, 81], dtype=torch.int32)
tensor([22,  5,  0, 31, 70, 45, 72, 42, 69, 12, 17, 41, 23, 54, 88, 60, 80, 90,
         2, 47, 27, 67, 13, 49, 18], dtype=torch.int32)
tensor([34, 71, 19, 39, 37, 55, 21, 43, 57, 86, 59, 83, 11, 38, 87,  9, 94, 84,
        63, 76, 53, 15, 75,  4, 44], dtype=torch.int32)
```

I'd further leave the validation set fixed. Split the validation data off and then only vary the size of the training data for an apples-to-apples comparison.

Edit:
For stratification, you can use `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection`. A strategy for defining a dataset could be to take as constructor arguments the `training_data` (complete), `labels` and the desired size.

```
class LimitedDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y, size, random_state=42):
        X_selected, _, y_selected, _ = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, train_size=size, random_state=random_state)
        self.X = X_selected
        self.y = y_selected

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.X[idx], self.y[idx]
```